# Is it possible to do Input/Output operations in parallel in C?

Tags: c, file-io, parallel-processing, openmp

I 'd like to write a large array in c in a .csv file.
Would it be possible to write it in parallel?

maybe using a OpenMP ?

The piece of code I'd like to parallelize is a typical IO operation in a file.
Given a resutVector1 and a resultVector2 of size n,

```
fp=fopen("output.csv","w+");
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    fprintf(fp,"%f,%f\n",resultVector1[i],resultVector2[i]);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: You are of course aware that a _text file_ is an inherently sequential data structure?

Comment: If you want to keep the order in the vector I would expect it is not possible.(at least not with the line of code you propose). And still writing to storage is afaik a sequential process on the architecture I am aware of. Still I would like If I am proven wrong.

Comment: If you're writing from separate threads or forks (processes) you could use a `mutex` to be sure each line was written in an atomic fashion. But be aware that unless you're doing dozens or hundreds of operations between each write that you'll be spending all of your time (idly) waiting for the mutex to become available.

This is definitely a case where you should avoid premature optimization.

Comment: I could see using `mmap` to map several areas of a file into memory, and have separate threads fill each.  The difficulty is that each segment needs to have a predetermined size, since a CSV is a text file, and the offset of a line of text in a text file depends on all the previous text.  So some sort of padding, or fixed length lines, or something

Comment: Plus `fopen` opens a stream which again is sequential if I remember it right.

Comment: Have you looked into MPI IO? http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/I590/node86.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to run into a number of problems trying to perform a parallel write to a single file.

w+ truncates an existing file to 0 length before the write operations or creates a new file, How are you going to coordinate the writing of parallel file pointers?

In any case if you have multiple writers, you will need to synchronize them and you will lose any speed advantage you would have had over a sequential write.  In fact, they will probably be slower due to the synchronization overhead than a single dedicated sequential write thread.

Thinking about your question a bit more.  If you really had a huge array, say 500 million integers and you really needed the fastest way to read/write this array to a persistent file.  You could divide the array by the number of dedicated threads you can allocate, write each segment to a separate file.  You can then read this array back into your array by doing a parallel read of this data.  In this case you can use a Parallel For type of pattern and avoid the synchronization lock overhead you have with a single file.

So in the example I gave, if you have 4 threads, you will divide the array inter quarters where each thread will write/read its own quarter to and from its separate file.

Note: if all the files are on the same disk drive you may have some I/O slowdown do the multiple simultaneous read/write operations going on at different parts of the disk.  This effect can be mediated if you are able to save each file to a different disk/server.

Comment: Well, it seems that HDF5 files can be read in [parallel](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/PHDF5/) as well as [Lustre](http://lustre.org/) and [XIOS](http://forge.ipsl.jussieu.fr/ioserver/wiki)

Comment: @MarouenBenGuebila Yes you are correct, but a HDFS file is not a monolithic file, but it is broken into many pieces and these can be read back simultaneously using a parallel read.  That is precisely the solution I described above.  You can divide array into subsections and white each one to its own file, and then you  read each of these files simultaneously through a parallel read.  This can be done on any OS that supports a parallel library and has multiple processors.

Answer (score 1):

You could open 2 files and write each vector in its own file, this MIGHT help but I won't bet on it, it would depend on the architecture of your platform I think. Plus if you need both in the same file you still have to copy it together, which again takes time.

Also the writes to the harddrive itself are probably the bottleneck here so there is no need to speed up the way you fill up the buffer to the harddrive.

You might open two files on two different harddrives, but I still doubt this would give you a real speed up.

Answer (score 1):

The question triggered me to write `pread`, a parallel read method implemented using `pthread` library. Given the file size `FILESIZE` and the number of threads `n`, `pread` method will slice the input file into roughly equal chunks of size `FILESIZE/n` and assign each chunk to a thread. Then, each thread starts reading the file using `fread` from different offsets of file with predefined `BUFFFERSIZE` in parallel. You can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/hmofrad/perfectlyparallel).

This is an ongoing implementation, I'm still working on parallel write side.